# Ubuntu 16.04 installer cant see SSD drive previously used as RAID

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I just replaced the hard drive on my desktop with an SSD HD. Ubuntu installer doesn't find it, although when I run Ubuntu from the live CD:

- the HD is detected in GParted, where I was able to create and format partitions.
- It's detected by the Ubuntu disks utility as well, and the partitions can be mounted, but when I tried to write a file to it it didn't work
- fdisk /dev/sda gives this:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sda: 139.8 GiB, 150039945216 bytes, 293046768 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x7da8b393

  Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
  /dev/sda1            2048 293046271 293044224 139.8G  5 Extended
  /dev/sda5            4096  71684095  71680000  34.2G 83 Linux
  /dev/sda6        71686144 102406143  30720000  14.7G 83 Linux
  /dev/sda7       102408192 270344191 167936000  80.1G 83 Linux
  /dev/sda8       270346240 293046271  22700032  10.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
  ```

I tried to change the BIOS SATA parameters to ACHI and tried a few other settings (not sure what that means but saw it might be related), it didn't help.

The HD is not new, **it was previously used as RAID in another computer**. I don't know how this works so I have no idea if that matters?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you have anything on this disk that you want?

Comment: @MarkYisri no it's empty, i just formatted it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If drive was previously part of a RAID set it may have RAID meta-data on it.
Change example from sdx to whatever drive is sda, sdb etc.

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdx
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do `dd if=/dev/zero of=YOUR_SSD_DRIVE bs=1024k count=10` then try again.
This will erase all metadata that may have been on the drive.