# 16.04 Boot Repair not working

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, asus

Using my Ubuntu USB backup, connected to the internet and followed instructions to download, install and run Boot Repair via Terminal.

From Terminal to run okay the first time but got message about Secure Boot needing to be turned off. Then it continued running, but problem was not solved and computer could not reboot.

Got message http://paste.ubuntu.com/26291725

Turned off Secure Boot, installed and ran etc again and it's stuck on the following.. Boot repair search mode has been running for more than several minutes...

[image: Boot Repair: scanning systems]

After some time I got the main graphical menu and selected the normal repair

Now this has been up for 20+ minutes with the Grub problem

[image: GRUB problem]

No idea what to do next...

---

*Update 1:*

Some time later the task was complete and I got the following message:

> An error occurred during the repair. A new file (/var/log/boot-repair/20171231_084453/Boot-Info_20171231_084‌​4.txt) will open in your text viewer. In case you still experience boot problem, indicate its content to: boot.repair@gmail.com Locked-ESP detected. You may want to retry after creating a /boot/efi partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option of [Boot Repair]

*Update 2:*

Sent logs to bootrepair email. Was not able to reboot from hard drive. Was able to boot up from Ubuntu USB and login (as you can see) to Ask Ubuntu via my Google ID. Checked email... no response yet.

*Update 3:*

Ran gparted as suggested above. Got the following error:

[image: Gparted I/O problem]

[image: SrartDatafail]

*Update 4:*

Ran gparted again. Results:

[image: Ran gparted again - results]

*Update 5:*

[image]

*Update 6:*

Should I run Gparted data rescue?

[image]

Message during startup:

[image: message during startup]

unable to handle kernel - crash during while running off of USB:

[image: unable to handle kernel - crash during while running off of USB]

close-up of kernel message:

[image: close-up of kernel message]

*Update (1.12.2018):*

[image: gparted screenshot]

[image: gparted screenshot]

This came up a few time before finishing gparted report:

[image: This came up a few time before finishing gparted report]

Comment: Locked ESP error. See if dosfsck like this works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/865872#865872 Others have had to back up the ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 with boot flag), delete it and then recreate it and restore files. But UUID & GUID then will change and other updates like reinstall grub and Windows UEFI boot entry are required.

Comment: @oldfred - Thanks, but I am a little lost. Should run sudo dosfsck-aAbflrtvVwy
in Terminal?

Comment: You need to run from terminal in live installer: `sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda1` and see if that solves issue or not.

Comment: Is the live installer the version of Ubuntu I am using that's on the USB? That' what I am using now. 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda1
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/sda1: 238 files, 42435/98304 clusters
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: Yes, and after the file check does gparted work or are there other issues? What brand/model system and what drive. Many SSD have needed firmware updates.

Comment: Ran gparted: Got message "Input/output error during read on /dev/sda". Clicked "Ignore" a few times and then results were displayed (image added to original post, above)

re: "... back up the ESP... (etc.) can you refer to detailed instructions? In the meantime should I "Attempt Data Rescue" (I have a cloud backup...)

ASUS 56; OS 16.04 (dual boot with Win 8.1); 12 GB RAM 750 GB HD (not SSD). 

Anticipating that it would be at least a good idea , I've ordered a SSD for delivery on Tuesday. 120 GB but can't see how large my current requirements are with Win + Ubu + about 60 GB data

Comment: It could be Windows is hibernated, or NTFS needs chkdsk or ext4 needs e2fsck. Windows often turns hibernation back on in background with updates, so even if you turned off the fast start up, you may have to turn it off again. Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI, possibly with f8 if Windows has errors. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Does it matter than I am not experiencing a problem with Windows? I am not trying to solve a Windows booting problem, and was considering getting rid of the Win OS anyway, as I only use for certain docs I need to create in Word.

Comment: With Windows you will not see an issue if it is hibernated. But that causes major issues for dual booting. Check if hibernated. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26305066/

I downloaded Unetbootin and tried to install it: 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unetbootin : Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable
              Depends: gksu but it is not installable or
                       kdesudo but it is not installable
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not installable
              Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: If at ubuntu@ubuntu that is live installer. You show normal install, just have way too many kernels and need to houseclean. So can you now boot from UEFI boot menu, both Windows entry & Ubuntu entry?

Comment: Windows boots up; Ubuntu almost gets there but then goes to Emergency Mode, etc.  e.g. "I/O error dev sda sector 771272704", "failed command" etc. 
Everything is backed up except for my Thunderbird email. If there is  a way to get that data I would consider starting from scratch with the new SSD I just got.

Comment: If from ubuntu@ubuntu live installler, you can mount the old drive, your data would be in /media/$USER/mountpoint or UUID/home/$USER/.thunderbird. I typically backup and copy entire profile for both Thunderbird and Firefox which are xxxxxx.default folders with all your files.http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder#Modify_profiles.ini_to_point_to_the_new_location_-_Advanced & 
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder

Comment: Seems I cannot access it - get a "no permissions " message. This is on the 50GB - the USB drive.  This and Computer seem to relate to the live installer, and then a volume called "OS" for Windows are mounted, but cannot be accessed.  I added graphic message above.

Comment: Do I need to become a Superuser? I have no log-in as I am in live installer mode... thanks.

Comment: @ToddEdelman it seems you have lost access to your original account. you can request to have them merged. Just use the link [contact](https://askubuntu.com/contact) at the bottom left of this page.

Answer (score 1):

Gparted error on sda3, system reserved is normal as that is required to be unformatted, but then gparted throws an error. The error on sda4 is only normal if you can directly boot Windows and then that says your have fast startup still on. But error on ext4 partition, sda8, says you may need fsck.Run both of these commands on sda8. [Ubuntu 14.04 is not booting normaly after a manual hard boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71696/discussion-on-answer-by-oldfred-16-04-boot-repair-not-working).