# Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubefi: Volume Corrupt

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Everything was working fine until today when I didn't get GNU GRUB and it automatically took me to Windows. 
I checked many articles and followed this one
https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/
where the person said to try typing in cmd

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

followed by restart

Now the issue is that Samsung shows up and then error follows up

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt, buffersize 1000
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubefi: Volume Corrupt 
start_image0 returned Volume Corrupt
```

stays for few second then another messsage

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt, buffersize 1000
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubefi: Volume Corrupt
start_image0 returned Volume Corrupt
```

stays for few second then blue screen

```
ERROR
Could not install security protocol: (0x2) Invalid Parameter
```

I am posting this because I can't type any command besides opening Boot Menu which leads to same problem.

Comment: Clicking on Okay shows a message

Something has gone very wrong: 2 shim cannot continue, sorry.
*laptop shut downs*

Comment: Using a Windows repair disk you can mount the ESP - efi system partition and run chkdsk. Or from Ubuntu live installer run dosfsck on the ESP. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/865872#865872