# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't boot after install (black screen)

Tags: system-installation

Yes, this old chestnut.

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04.
Can get into `grub` fine (therefore I don't think it's an EFI problem), and if I choose the recovery option then the screen gets as far as

```
Loading initial ramdisk ...
_
```

For all other options the screen is just completely black (the backlight is on).

Kernel options `nomodeset`, `quiet`, `splash`, `acpi=off` make no difference and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't do anything.

How can it be made to work?
Very disappointed :'(

**Update: Super Grub2 Disk**

It prints `error: unknown filesystem`. nine times then `Entering rescue mode ...` then a prompt `grub rescue >`.

However, if I run the *live CD* from the Ubuntu installer then

```
$ lsblk -o value -s TYPE /dev/sda1
vfat
$ lsblk -o value -s TYPE /dev/sda2
ext4
```

so I dispute that these are unknown filesystems.

Comment: Get on another PC and make a bootable USB of this sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2 it has never let me down in the field. Post your results so some experts can chime in if it doesn't get you going.

Comment: There is the partition table which says what file system you have & the filesystem itself. If issue with filesystem, it then may throw an error as it does not match partition table. Often corruption from abnormal shutdown. if you can get to recovery mode with partitions unmounted you can run fsck from there, otherwise live installer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 There also is dosfsck for the ESP(FAT32). https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872