# Ubuntu 21.04. Gparted warning symbol. How to fix FAT32 EFI partition? Or can I ignore it?

Tags: uefi, gparted

I got a 2TB external NVME drive. Using Clonezilla on a Live USB, I want to clone my internal Ubuntu drive to this external drive. See here https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdYDr.jpg Red exclamation point on EFI FAT32 partition. How to fix?

I ran the Gparted “Check” command on this FAT32 EFI partition and the results came back all green/good, but the red exclamation point is still there.

Can I ignore this error warning? I don’t need to or plan to connect this external drive to a Windows pc.
.-
.-
[image]

Comment: I do not recommend clone of drives a you cannot reboot with  both. Often easier just to reinstall. Have you tried dosfsck? https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872 UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  But with external drive: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1840560 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Comment: Did you install dosfstools and mtools?

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the FAT32 partition and click on 'Information' in the menu which pops up, you will probably see:

```
! Warning:
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for fat32 file
system support:  dosfstools, mtools.
```

At least this is what I often get; e.g. on current Ubuntu installation USBs, `dosfstools` is present but `mtools` is not.

So `sudo apt install mtools` fixes the issue.