# GRUB does not load after update, opening Windows Boot Loader instead

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I just updated Ubuntu and wanted to restart my Lenovo s440.

Normally, the system goes through the GRUB loader. Now the whole system is messed up. Either, I am stuck at the Lenovo screen in the beginning or it goes straight to Windows.

In the BIOS, ubuntu is the first option. The second is the Windows boot manager.

I tried setting the EFI in Windows but although it says success, there is no change in behavior.

The only way I can access GRUB and Ubuntu is the following, opening BIOS and changing something. Then saving and discarding changes. (It does not work when there was no change in the settings) This allows me to access GRUB and choose the OS. However, that does not seem like a permanent option...

My problem is a bit vague. But I hope to get back to a situation in which GRUB automatically starts when i switch on the PC, instead of freezing or going directly to Windows.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My problem is a bit vague. But I hope to get back to a situation in which GRUB automatically starts when i switch on the PC, instead of freezing or going directly to Windows.

Comment: Did system also do a Windows update & turn fast start up on, or reset some UEFI settings. Check those settings in Windows & UEFI first. Grub only boots working Windows. You should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Boot-Repair only can fix Linux issues, not Windows.

Comment: hi @oldfred thanks a lot for your help! https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jPb83hvYyS/ i did not change anything and had no windows update...

Comment: Report did not show /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, it usually does. Need to know ESP does not need repairs (dosfsck) or the the grub configfile entry in ESP is to correct install. But if newer system, you may need 20.04.3 or even 21.04 versions of Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872

Comment: ok, i installed v20.04.3. It starts into ubuntu directly (it still does not load grub but for the moment i just want a working ubuntu distro on my pc...). Thanks a lot for your help!