# Ubuntu boots a long time

Tags: boot

After some manipulations with the fdisk utility, my Ubuntu system began to boot for a long time - everything was fine before. I can't figure out what happened and how to get back to the previous state. Also I should note that I don't have any other problems. Please explain me how I can investigate my problem and understand what is happened. Below is more info about my system, boot log and etc.

In my boot log I see : `"A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/BA7A-9BA0 (10s / 1min 30s)"`. I seems to me that jos is related to `/dev/nvme0n1p2(hard disk)`.

[image]

[image]

```
roman@roman-HP-470-G8-Notebook-PC:/proc/1917$ lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop1       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/code/112
loop2       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/code/113
loop3       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core18/2632
loop4       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core20/1695
loop5       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core/13886
loop6       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/30
loop7       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core20/1634
loop8       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop9       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/discord/143
loop10      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core22/275
loop11      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/29
loop12      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/discord/145
loop13      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop14      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core22/310
loop15      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core/14056
loop16      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core18/2620
loop17      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop18      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop19      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop20      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/opera/209
loop21      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop22      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/44
loop23      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snap-store/592
loop24      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/opera/208
loop25      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/postman/183
loop26      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/postman/184
loop27      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snap-store/599
loop28      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snapd/17336
loop29      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop30      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snapd/17576
loop31      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/telegram-desktop/4312
loop32      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/whatsapp-for-linux/48
loop33      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/telegram-desktop/4353
loop34      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/zoom-client/192
loop35      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/zoom-client/193
nvme0n1                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p1                                                                    
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4           d23d886f-f1c8-43a8-bfd0-b6d61d6e22f6  364,8G    17% /run/timeshift/backup



roman@roman-HP-470-G8-Notebook-PC:/proc/1917$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=d23d886f-f1c8-43a8-bfd0-b6d61d6e22f6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=BA7A-9BA0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Your p2 is your / (root). What is BA7A-9BA0? Post this above in question. `lsblk -f` And post this: `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: Results from these commands have been added

Comment: Should have said to exclude loops as they are just all your snaps. I do not allow snaps on my system to my test to confirm command just showed partitions. Your BA7A-9BA0 is your ESP on p1. I might try from live installer so unmounted run dosfsck. https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872  or `sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/nvme0n1p1`