iMac with Ubuntu and rEFInd
I've been trying to install Ubuntu on an iMac that I was given. I must have spent the best part of the weekend trying to get this to work, but it was not as easy as I first thought.
I am experienced Linux tech. I am comfortable on the on the command line, and have a decent understanding of hardware.
I am unable to boot into the Ubuntu OS having installed.
iMac serial number: C02P54UWF8J4

I have a working wired internet connection that when plugged into the iMac with live USB allows me to connect to the internet, and a live USB stick which I created with Rufus
I have rEFInd installed and a copy of the binaries on USB key. I followed the steps from this video to create it
Mac keyboard wired and regular wired USB mouse
What I have done so far:

I've installed the Ubuntu on the entire partition on the iMac during the install I selected the option to “install third-party software for graphics and wifi hardware”  and  “Download and install support for additional media formats”

Rebooted the machine

After that I got the ‘? Folder' and a link to support/apple.com/mac/startup


I know that the fix to this is to hold cmd + R and launch the terminal and install rEFInd to be more exact refind-bin-0.14.2

It does seem to pick the Linux partition red arrow above.
On the iMac I have the following when I look at the disks from Recovery mode and I get the following
I do a verify and I get the following.

I do a repair and get the following.

It seems that all is healthy from the perspective.
I then reboot the iMac, but I get the following screen for rEFInd.

But no option to pick the Linux OS that I have just installed.
When I select blue ‘i’ I get the following

I pop in the live USB stick. I do get the following and then I get the following options. These all seem to be only to be able to boot from the USB stick

If I boot into the first one, then I get boot into the live distro
I get the following screen for a second.

After that I get the following grub screen.

When I go to GParted I see the following.

When I select /dev/sda1 I get the following

If I try to run the installer again, I see the following when I look at the partitions.

So it does appear to be there circle 1.
Circle 2 has a dropdown which I have shown below.

Just to be sure that the OS is there I have mounted  /dev/sda2 on a directory that I created called  /temp and when I go to /temp I can see the file structure of an whole OS so it does appear to be there.
It all seems to be in place, but for some reason rEFInd is not able to see the Linux OS partition (or something similar).
I tried @oldfred's suggestion and below is the output

Post the reboot only got the blue arrow as per the 5th screen grab from the top.

All that info and you do not mention Mac version, just serial number. From what I have seen every Mac version/year has differences. If gparted does not like your ESP, I might run dosfsck on it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872
dosfstools - dosfsck (aka fsck.msdos and fsck.vfat) utilities
Must be unmounted
sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda1  Very new M1 and newer may not work without special software. Older one: Install to Mac 4.1
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365454&p=13663640#post13663640

@oldfred have added that info now too to the top of the post/question .  Did your steps no longer get warning on /dev/sda1 when in gparted  and have put results above but after reboot still got the only got the blue arrow in rEFInd no OS to pick from.

I have only used rEFInd on my PC as emergency boot & it just worked without any special settings. So cannot really help. Old info, usually newer releases resolve those types of issues. New Haswell MacBook Air - several issues
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=apple_mba2013_ubuntu&num=1
This bug should not apply anymore: Bugs Ubuntu fails to properly boot on Macbook Air 2013 6,1 & 6,2 - Use UEFI not CSM
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1197451
